# Wordpress error when sending comment

Tags: wordpress, comments

I'm using the default comments template, on my own self-built theme. When I send a comment I get the following error message:

**Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_set_comment_cookies' not found or invalid function name in /home/mattator/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 403**

**Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mattator/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:403) in /home/mattator/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 881**

couldn't find a call to the funciton 'wp_set_comment_cookies' anywhere in the code. **It is noteworthy that despite the error message the comment is being sent properly**. I also tried to disable all plugins but the problem persists.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have some extra white space before

```
<?php
```

tag in starting of a theme file

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I experimented a little bit, and as turns out the problem was a call to the function "nocache_headers()", in Line 18 of the file "wp-comments-post.php" which lies at WP root directory.
I deleted it, and voila, everything works. Not sure why though.